# Can I split my target keyphrase to make grammatical sense, or do I need to use it verbatim for SEO?

Tags: seo, keywords, content

My keyword is "website performance zurich".

My content should be about to say that we are a web agency in Zurich that can optimize the performance of your website.

If I use the keyword exactly the same as it is for my title and paragraphs, they look unnatural and not really readable.

For instance:

This looks not good: We provide **website performance Zurich**.

This looks better: We are a web agency in **Zurich** and can provide you a better **performance** for your **website**.

Also, it is quite an overkill, when I mention the location (Zurich), every time where the keyword has been set in my content. The location is placed in my footer and that should be enough, but I understand that I have to mention it somewhere in my content since it belongs to my keyword. Maybe I can write the location once in the content, but repeating it over and over again is unnecessary.

So where do I get a higher ranking? Writing the keyword exactly the same as it is, although the sentence is not 100 % readable? Or splitting the keyword but then not placing the keyword as one piece, but instead it is easier to read?

Comment: Always write content for your visitors preferntially, not search engines.